# Is it possible to make trigger bounce

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to make chest from which coins jumps. I've make wealth prefabs with colliders and rigidbodys so wealth jumps, but colliders stay and on collision enter with player player is stucks for little time, so I want wealth prefabs to be triggers, but triggers doesn't bounce as I want.

```
 private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {//on collision enter with ground
        if (gameObject.tag == "Wealth" && collision.gameObject.layer == 8) {
            gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector3.zero;
            gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().angularVelocity = 0;
        }
    }
```

Coins add

```
private void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D collision) {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Wealth") {
            coinCount += 1;
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        }
    }
```

I saw it in this video:
https://youtu.be/ozJ3FyatFKo
Could anyone tell how I caould do this?

Comment: it is onCollision**STAY** to pick coins up, perhaps that was reason for coinsto not be picked up without delay?

Comment: I thought that collision enter with prefab and player will work faster than collision stay?

Comment: Yea, but what i see is you using is " stay" this is why i suggsted this may be causing initial issue.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't help. Delay is still there. Btw I want prefabs to be triggers so it could look like on the video

Comment: Another idea i jsut had is that colision is fast and if you have " collision detection" on rigidbody set on discrete that may be causing slight delay.

Comment: No, it is continuous on player and wealth prefabs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224602/discussion-between-tomasz-and-wanheda).